# Is there a programmatic way to change vsync at runtime in Haxe/Starling?

Tags: haxe, openfl, vsync

I see a way to do so through `project.xml` but I'm not seeing a way to disable/enable vsync at runtime (like for example having an option in a settings menu or something). Searching hasn't given me any answers. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be up to [Lime](https://github.com/openfl/lime), which OpenFL is built on top of. Lime itself is built on top of [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), but you can only access the SDL API indirectly through Lime.

Looking through Lime sources and commit history, what you're after doesn't seem to be supported right now - the vsync flag is only passed to the initial `CreateWindow()` call, there doesn't seem to be a way to change it after the fact / without creating a new window.

This same question was discussed [in the OpenFL forums](https://community.openfl.org/t/programmatically-change-vsync/8224) a few years ago. There, an idea of how this could be implemented in Lime by re-creating the [SDL renderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer) with different flags (specifying `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` vs not specifying it) was proposed. If you need this feature, you could consider having a go at implementing it yourself and creating a pull request.